# Loop a 2 letter range

Tags: php, combinatorics

I'm trying to achieve a loop over all possible 2 letter combinations.
Something like

`foreach(range(aa,zz) as $i) {...}`

My current solution is:

```
foreach (range(a, z) as $first) {
    foreach (range(a, z) as $second) {
        //all 2 letter combinations
        echo $first.$second;
    }
}
```

This makes me worry that if I needed all possible 10 letter combinations, there would be 10 loops involved.

**Is there a better way to achieve this?**

Comment: If you need to do something 141 trillion (=26^10) times, then you probably shouldn't be using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over letters using a simple for loop :

```
for ($letter = 'aa'; $letter != 'aaa'; ++$letter) {
  echo $letter . '<br>';
}
```

Output :

```
aa
ab
...
zy
zz
```

Comment: @GundarsMēness I updated my answer with a much proper way to do it. (Stop the loop without using break) I was confused on the char/string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
$b = array('q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
for($i = 26;$i <= 1000;$i++)
    echo str_replace($a,$b,base_convert ( $i, 10 , 26))."<br />";
```

just put in the right starting and end positions.