# Why does this for-loop comparison fail after auto-incrementing on letters

Tags: php, for-loop, comparison

I just gave this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688064/2627459 in order to loop over letters combination, with the following code :

```
for ($letter = 'a'; ; ++$letter) {
  echo $letter . '<br>';
  if ($letter == 'zz') break;
}
```

Which is just working fine.

I then tried to move the `break` into the `for` loop comparison, feeling that it would be better :

```
for ($letter = 'a'; $letter < 'zz'; ++$letter) {
  echo $letter . '<br>';
}
```

But of course, the last value (`zz`) wasn't showing, so I tried :

```
for ($letter = 'a'; $letter < 'aaa'; ++$letter) {
  echo $letter . '<br>';
}
```

And I don't know why, but it's giving me the following output :

```
a
```

So I tried several entries, and the (weird) results are :

Entry : `$letter < 'yz'` -
Output : Up to `y` only

Entry : `$letter < 'zzz'` -
Output : Up to `zzy`

I don't get why it works when the chain starts with `z`, but it fails in any other case (letter).

Morover, in the case of `$letter < 'aaa'`, it displays `a`, but not the next one. At worst, I would have expected it to fail with `a < 'aaa'` and so display **nothing**. But no.

So, where does this behavior come from, am I missing something on how PHP compare these values ?

(I'm not looking for a workaround, but for an explanation. By the way, if any explanation comes with a working code, it's perfect !)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparison is alphabetic:

```
$letter < 'yz'
```

When you get to `y`, you increment again and get `z`..... alphabetically, `z` is greater than `yz`

If you use

```
    $letter != 'yz'
```

for your comparison instead, it will give you up to `yy`

So

```
for ($letter = 'a'; $letter !== 'aaa'; ++$letter) {
    echo $letter . '<br>';
}
```

will give from `a`, through `z`, `aa`, `ab`.... `az`, `ba`.... through to `zz`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098345/why-doesnt-this-code-simply-print-letters-a-to-z/4098414#4098414) and related comments

**EDIT**

Personally I like incrementing the endpoint, so

```
$start = 'A';
$end = 'XFD';

$end++;
for ($char = $start; $char !== $end; ++$char) {
    echo $char, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Hum, at some point I tried `$letter != 'aaa'` but it didn't work, that's why I went with the if-break solution. A typo for sure ... Anyway, thanks for the link, I couldn't find this by myself. Confusing concept imho !